# Macbook Air M2 screen sharing no longer works

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ventura, screen-sharing

I have a fairly new Macbook Air M2 laptop (Aug 2023) that I use for work.  When working at home, I have been using an older iMac via screen sharing to connect to the laptop so I get the bigger screen, keyboard and mouse.  This worked fine sometime back in November, but it doesn't work any more.  It's definitely the laptop, I've tried a very very old iMac (2007) a slightly newer iMac (2009) and a new iMac (2022).  I cannot connect via screensharing from any of them, screen sharing app launches and says "Connecting to Dave's MacBook Air" until it times out with a "could not connect, check firewall, etc." message.  None of these machines has firewall turned on.  Laptop is Ventura 13.3.  I tried opening up Screen Sharing perms on the laptop to "Any User" with no success.  I've rebooted all of these machines.  Any thoughts and what to look at?  I'm a unix/linux sysadmin but am a bit perplexed by the Apple syslogs... not at all intuitive to use.  AT ALL.  FWIW I also tried connecting with the VNC Viewer app which also did not work.

Comment: I'd at least update Ventura first to eliminate the possibility of a bug since fixed. Latest is 13.6.3 from Dec '23.

Comment: If Remote Management is enabled, please disable it and test. Otherwise, does File Sharing work?

Comment: I upgraded to 13.6.3 and that solved the problem.  Thanks much!